# How to tell a method to use a specific constant when called?

Tags: c#, function, variables

I am trying to build a Log function.
My class looks a bit like this (pseudoCode):

```
const string Trigger1 = "Warning";
const string Trigger2 = "Info";

public void log (string Trigger) 
{
    WriteLog(message = Trigger);
}
```

I want to call the method log and tell it which Trigger constant it should write in the log.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: How are you deciding which message to use? It isn't clear in your code.

Comment: Use a logger library like log4net.  The verbosity is provided automatically (as an output and a logging level) and is far more useful than a constant string.

Comment: `log(Trigger1);` or `log(Trigger2);`

Comment: I am not following at all, if you want to use a specific variable, then just _pass that variable to the method_.

Comment: Make two variants: public void `LogWarning(string Trigger)` and `LogError(string Trigger)`, and make each use the appropriate constant

Comment: [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) is also a great logging utility.  Lots of "sinks" you can use (console, rolling file, email, etc)

Answer (score 1):

You should use log library, but if you are just experimenting and want to implement this yourself use Enums.

```
public enum LogLevel {
    Warning,
    Info
}

Log(LogLevel.Info);

public void Log(LogLevel level) {
...
}
```

Comment: You can also call ToString on the level parameter to get the string value. ("Warning" and "Info")

Answer (score 1):

You can do what most log libraries do and be explicit in your API:

```
public class Logger
{
    private const string Warn = "Warn";
    private const string Info = "Info";

    public LogInfo(string message)
    {
        Log(Info, message);
    }

    public LogWarn(string message)
    {
         Log(Warn, message);
    }

    private Log(string trigger, string message)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

As another option you might choose to expose the `private Log` method above as part of your public API. In that case I would extract the LogLevel as an enum and use it as the trigger argument instead of using a `string`